Mathematical Hierarchies Collapsing at Level 2
I am looking for (many) examples of mathematical hierarchies like the arithmetical or the polynomial hierarchy that collapse precisely at level 2 (3 is also fine, but the level should be at least 2 and yet relatively low).
Some background:
The arithmetical hierarchy, for example, is a quantifier alternation depth hierarchy.
The formula
$$\Xi ~{}={}~ \forall x \colon \varphi \qquad \text{would be at level 1}$$
of the hierarchy,
the formula
$$\Phi ~{}={}~ \forall\, w ~\forall\, x ~\exists\,y  ~\exists\, z\colon \phi \qquad \text{would be at level 2}$$
of the hierarchy, and the formula
$$\Psi ~{}={}~ \exists\, w ~\exists\, x ~\color{orange}{\forall\,y  ~\exists\, z}\colon \phi\qquad \text{would be at level 3}$$
of the hierarchy.
If I understand correctly, if the arithmetical hierarchy were to collapse at level 2 (which it in fact does not), then the formula $\Psi$ would be equivalent to the formula $ \color{orange}{\forall\,y  ~\exists\, z}\colon \phi$ because the leading existential quantifiers of $\Psi$ would not add any extra complexity / information to what the formula expresses.
I am looking for examples of mathematical hierarchies that are strict (not all levels are in fact the same) but which collapse at some relatively low level $k$ (meaning that all levels above $k$ are actually the same as level $k$), where preferrably $k=2$.

This question may be of interest.

Yes it is, thank you! : )
